# Почему более нижние объекты залезают на более верхние в юнити tilemaps?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я расставляю на уровне деревья спомощью tilemaps. У меня есть тайлы деревьев, они разные, я хочу их расставить: это будет лес, от которого игроку нужно будет освободиться, чтобы получить больше пространства для строительства.

Однако у меня почему-то нижняя часть деревьев, ствол, залезает на крону деревьев, распологающихся клеткой выше. Я только начал изучать изометрию и tilemaps, поэтому, возможно, мой вопрос простой и, может быть, даже глупый. Но я был бы благодарен вам, если вы подскажите, как это исправить.

[image: Стволы залезают на крону]

Если что, мои tilemaps'ы просто изометрические (без изометрия Z как Y), однако я пробовал и так, но ничего особо не изменилось. Располагаю деревья и зеленые блоки травы в разных объектах на разных tilemaps'ах - GridBase и GridDecor.

Comment: в юнити есть родная сортировка лееров. Вероятнее ты размещаешь ягоды на леере который отрисовывается последним и поверх всего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос сам.
Нужно было просто добавить на DecorGrid такой компонент как SortingGrid, а также в Project Settings установить Transparency Sort Axis с (0;0;1) на (0;1;0)